# Flutter app testing with docker and Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, android-studio, flutter

I'm new to creating an app, and I want to know how to test my backend api in android studio. I have installed docker and Postgres. How do I connect it to android studio and view it on the simulator?